# Validating function written in javaScript runs only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, if-statement

**goal** :  is to validate this form. http://jsbin.com/buwejurexa/1/
Code is below

Show the user all errors at once when he clicks Save Product button and errors at each step also.

**What is done**:
Wrote a validating function returnVal() which is nested inside another function called displayStorage.

**What works** : 
As the page loads the user clicks the Save Product button and the validating function seems to be working first time. I can see the alert.

**The issue starts when**:

- The user selects the Category and Products and sees Wattage. This
  time he decides to click on Save Product. Nothing happens. No
  Validations are displayed step by step.
- No errors in Console but got a error in JS Bin that (Line 253: Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment.
  Line 258: Unreachable 'return' after 'return'.)

My guess : 
a) my if and else statement is missing something. I tried calling it from different functions but no luck.

b) The four buttons use Jquery. so I am guessing do I need to call javascript function returnVal() inside Jquery.  How do I do that. I did reference the 4 buttons in my validating function.

can some help me get the validations right.

Thanks!!

```js
var wattage = {
  'Artic King AEB': 100,
  'Artic King ATMA': 200,
  'Avanti Compact': 300,
  'Bosch SS': 400,
  'Bosch - SHXUC': 100,
  'Asko DS': 200,
  'Blomberg': 300,
  'Amana': 400
};
var annualEnergy = 0;
var dailyEnergyConsumed = 0;



function populateProducts(category, products) {

  var refrigerators = new Array('Artic King AEB', 'Artic King ATMA', 'Avanti Compact', 'Bosch SS');
  var dishWasher = new Array('Bosch - SHXUC', 'Asko DS', 'Blomberg', 'Amana');


  switch (category.value) {
    case 'refrigerators':
      products.options.length = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < refrigerators.length; i++) {
        createOption(products, refrigerators[i], refrigerators[i]);
      }

      break;
    case 'dishWasher':
      products.options.length = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < dishWasher.length; i++) {
        createOption(products, dishWasher[i], dishWasher[i]);
      }
      break;
    default:
      products.options.length = 0;
      break;
  }

  populateWattage(products);
}


function createOption(ddl, text, value) {
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.value = value;
  opt.text = text;
  ddl.options.add(opt);
}

function populateWattage(product) {
  document.getElementById('wattage').innerText = wattage[product.value];

  populateStorage();


}

function setConsumption(hrs) {
  setConsumption();


}

dailyEnergyConsumption = function(hrs) {

  dailyEnergyConsumed = 0;
  dailyEnergyConsumed = parseFloat(hrs * parseInt(document.getElementById('wattage').innerText) / 1000).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('dailyEnergyConsumptionVal').innerText = dailyEnergyConsumed + " kWh";

  populateStorage();



};


annualEnergyConsumption = function(days) {

  annualEnergy = 0;


  var allYear = document.getElementById('allYear');
  var halfYear = document.getElementById('halfYear');
  var threeMonths = document.getElementById('threeMonths');
  var oneMonth = document.getElementById('oneMonth');

  if (allYear || days != 365) {
    annualEnergy = parseFloat(dailyEnergyConsumed * parseInt(days)).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('annualEnergyConsumption').innerText = annualEnergy + " kWh";

  } else if (days == 182 && !halfYear) {
    annualEnergy = parseFloat(dailyEnergyConsumed * parseInt(days)).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('annualEnergyConsumption').innerText = annualEnergy + " kWh";
  } else if (days == 90 && !threeMonths) {
    annualEnergy = parseFloat(dailyEnergyConsumed * parseInt(days)).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('annualEnergyConsumption').innerText = annualEnergy + " kWh";
  } else if (days == 30 && !oneMonth) {
    annualEnergy = parseFloat(dailyEnergyConsumed * parseInt(days)).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('annualEnergyConsumption').innerText = annualEnergy + " kWh";
  }

  populateStorage();

};


// code that shows which button is clicked. Green div below the 4 buttons
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#h1").click(function() {
    $("#onesSelected").show();

    $("#threeSelected").hide();
    $("#sixSelected").hide();
    $("#twentyFourSelected").hide();

  });

  $("#h3").click(function() {
    $("#threeSelected").show();

    $("#onesSelected").hide();
    $("#sixSelected").hide();
    $("#twentyFourSelected").hide();

  });


  $("#h6").click(function() {
    $("#sixSelected").show();

    $("#onesSelected").hide();
    $("#threeSelected").hide();
    $("#twentyFourSelected").hide();

  });
  $("#h24").click(function() {

    $("#twentyFourSelected").show();

    $("#onesSelected").hide();
    $("#threeSelected").hide();
    $("#sixSelected").hide();


  });



});


function compareSetup() {

  var prodName = localStorage.getItem('productKey');
  var energyName = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('energyKey'), 10);
  var useName = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('estimatedUse'), 10);

  return false;
}

function populateStorage() {

  var productBox = document.getElementById("products");
  var productName = productBox.options[productBox.selectedIndex].text;

  localStorage.setItem('productKey', productName);
  localStorage.setItem('energyKey', document.getElementById("annualEnergyConsumption").innerHTML);

  //localStorage.setItem.querySelector('input[id="usageRadio"]:checked').value;
  //localStorage.setItem('usageRadio' + $(this).attr('id'), JSON.stringify({ checked: this.checked }));
  //localStorage.setItem('estimatedUse', document.getElementById("usageRadio"));

  // do other things if necessary
}

function displayStorage() {

    var displayProduct = document.getElementById("displayName");
    var displayAnnual = document.getElementById("displayAnnual");

    displayProduct.innerHTML = "Selected Product: " + localStorage.getItem('productKey');
    displayProduct.style = "display:inline;";
    displayAnnual.innerHTML = "Annual Consumption: " + localStorage.getItem('energyKey');

    returnVal();

  }
  //validation code starts here

function returnVal() {

  //initialize the form elements starting from form name , category and product dropdown, daily use buttons and finally the radio buttons
  var energyForm = document.getElementsByName("energyForm")[0];

  // drop downs
  var catDropdown = document.getElementById("dd1");
  var prodDropdown = document.getElementById("products");


  // call the 4 Daily use button
  var notLotButton = document.getElementById("h1");
  var averageButton = document.getElementById("h3");
  var lotButton = document.getElementById("h6");
  var alwaysButton = document.getElementById("h24");

  // radio button group
  var allYearRadio = document.getElementById("allYear");
  var halfYearRadio = document.getElementById("halfYear");
  var threeMonthsRadio = document.getElementById("threeMonths");
  var oneMonthRadio = document.getElementById("oneMonth");

  // 
  var missingFields = false;
  var strFields = "";

  if (catDropdown.selectedIndex === 0) {
    missingFields = true;
    strFields += "Select Category and the related Product \n";
    catDropdown.focus();

  } else {
    return true;
  }


  if ((!notLotButton.clicked) &&
    (!averageButton.clicked) &&
    (!lotButton.clicked) &&
    (!alwaysButton.clicked)) {

    missingFields = true;
    strFields += "Select atleast one Estimated Daily Use option \n";


  } else {
    return true;
  }

  if ((!allYearRadio.checked) &&
    (!halfYearRadio.checked) &&
    (!threeMonthsRadio.checked) &&
    (!oneMonthRadio.checked)) {
    missingFields = true;
    strFields += "Select atleast one Estimated Yearly Use option \n";


  } else {
    return true;
  }

  if (missingFields = true) {
    alert("Please provide the following fields before continuing: \n" + strFields);
  }
  return false;

  return true;
}


function resetForm() {

  document.getElementById("resetButton");
  document.getElementById("energyForm").reset();
  document.getElementById('products').value = "select";

  //document.getElementById('select_value').selectedIndex = 3;


}
```

```css
#leftColumn {

  width: 600px;

  float: left;

}

.placeholderText {

  font: bold 12px/30px Georgia, serif;

}

body {

  padding-left: 45px;

}

#annualEnergyConsumption {

  font: bold 25px arial, sans-serif;

  color: #00ff00;

}

#dailyEnergyConsumptionVal {

  font: bold 25px arial, sans-serif;

  color: #00ff00;

}

#annualCostOperation {

  font: bold 40px arial, sans-serif;

  color: #00ff00;

}

.dailyButInline {

  display: inline;

}

#wattage {

  position: absolute;

  left: 160px;

  top: 130px;

  font: bold 25px arial, sans-serif;

  color: #00ff00;

}

/* mouse over link */

button:hover {

  background-color: #b6b6b6;

}

#onesSelected {

  position: absolute;

  left: 53px;

  top: 246px;

  background-color: #00ff00;

  display: none;

  width: 99px;

  height: 5px;

}

#threeSelected {

  position: absolute;

  left: 156px;

  top: 246px;

  background-color: #00ff00;

  display: none;

  width: 99px;

  height: 5px;

}

#sixSelected {

  position: absolute;

  left: 259px;

  top: 246px;

  background-color: #00ff00;

  display: none;

  width: 99px;

  height: 5px;

}

#twentyFourSelected {

  position: absolute;

  left: 362px;

  top: 246px;

  background-color: #00ff00;

  display: none;

  width: 113px;

  height: 5px;

}

#store {

  cursor: pointer;

}
```

```html
<h2>Annual Energy Consumption and Cost Calculator</h2>

<form id="energyForm" onSubmit="return compareSetup()" action="" method="post">

  <div id="leftColumn">

    <div>
      <span class="placeholderText">Choose Category</span>
      <span>
  <select id="dd1" name="dd1" onchange="populateProducts(this,document.getElementById('products'))" required>
   <option value="select">Select-a-Category</option>
   <option value="refrigerators">Refrigerators</option>
   <option value="dishWasher">DishWasher</option>
   </select>
  </span>
      </br>

      <span class="placeholderText">Select a Product</span>
      <span>
  <select id="products" onchange="populateWattage(this)" required>
    <option value="select" selected>--------------------------</option>
  </select>
  </span>


    </div>

    <div>
      <span class="placeholderText">Wattage</span>
      <span id="wattage">0</span>
      </br>
      </br>
    </div>

    <div id="buttonBoundary">
      <div class="placeholderText">Estimated Daily Use</div>

      <div class="dailyButInline">
        <button type="button" id="h1" onclick="dailyEnergyConsumption(1)">Not a Lot</br>1 hour per day</button>
      </div>
      <div class="dailyButInline">
        <button type="button" id="h3" onclick="dailyEnergyConsumption(3)">Average</br>3 hour per day</button>
      </div>
      <div class="dailyButInline">
        <button type="button" id="h6" onclick="dailyEnergyConsumption(6)">A Lot</br>6 hour per day</button>
      </div>
      <div class="dailyButInline">
        <button type="button" id="h24" onclick="dailyEnergyConsumption(24)">Always On</br>24 hours per day</button>
      </div>


      <div id="onesSelected"></div>
      <div id="threeSelected"></div>
      <div id="sixSelected"></div>
      <div id="twentyFourSelected"></div>

      </br>
      </br>


    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="placeholderText">Daily Energy Consumption</span>
      </br>
      <div id="dailyEnergyConsumptionVal">---</div>
      </br>
    </div>


    <div>
      <span class="placeholderText">Estimated Yearly Use</span>
      </br>


      <input type="radio" name="usageRadio" value="365" id="allYear" onclick="annualEnergyConsumption(365)" />
      <label for="allYear">All year</label>

      <input type="radio" name="usageRadio" value="182" id="halfYear" onclick="annualEnergyConsumption(182)" />
      <label for="halfYear">6 Months</label>

      <input type="radio" name="usageRadio" value="90" id="threeMonths" onclick="annualEnergyConsumption(90)" />
      <label for="threeMonths">3 Months</label>


      <input type="radio" name="usageRadio" value="30" id="oneMonth" onclick="annualEnergyConsumption(30)" />
      <label for="oneMonth">1 Month</label>
      <!-- <div id="daysUsed"><input type="number" id="hour" maxlength="2" min="1" onchange="annualEnergyConsumption(this.value)"></br> -->

    </div>
    </br>
    <div>
      <span class="placeholderText">Energy Consumption</span>
      </br>
      <div id="annualEnergyConsumption">---</div>
      </br>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Save Product" onclick="displayStorage()" />

    <input type="reset" onclick="resetForm()" id="resetButton" value="Reset" />
  </div>



  <div id="right">
    <div id="displayName">Selected Product:</div>
    <div id="displayAnnual">Annual Consumption:</div>






  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Put the code IN the question (and optionally in a fiddle but SO supports snippets).

Comment: Look at the line JSBin is pointing you to: `if (missingFields = true)` note that `=` and `==` are two very different operators.

Comment: I wanted to check if missingFields are true. did I assign true instead of checking.

Comment: @Accidental_Everything: Yes. You did.

Comment: @Matt :  Can JS function have more than one return statement. I am blanking out why I added the return statement at end. I commented the last return and that error is gone. But my validations still dont work

Comment: @Accidental_Everything: You can only return from a function once (obviously). Probably you meant to put one of those returns (assuming the `false` one) inside the `if` statement so that you will return `false` if `missingFields == true` else return `true`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77726/discussion-between-accidental-everything-and-matt-burland).

Comment: Can some one help me for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the last statements of your function, there are two mistakes:

```
  if (missingFields = true) { // should be: missingFields == true
    alert("Please provide the following fields before continuing: \n" + strFields);
  }
  return false;

  return true; // You already returned false; did you mean to return false inside the if?
```

Comment: Thanks. I have written only a handful of functions. Sorry.      When I wrote this I thought  - after I check all the fields if there are any missing fields show me the alert else dont show.

Comment: if (missingFields === true) {
    alert("Please provide the following fields before continuing: \n" + strFields);
     return false;
    }
    else {
                    return true;
                }

Comment: this does not seem to work either. My validations dont come through